# Getting "argument is not defined" error while running the javascript from Selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

TestCase class is where I initailize the driver and invoke the url (url "http://www.amazon.in/")

```
public class TestCase { 
    InitializeDriver id = new InitializeDriver();
    WebDriver driver = null;

    @BeforeTest
    public void setup()
    {
        id.invokeApplicationUrl();
        driver = id.getDriver();

    }

}
```

TC1 is my test to go to Amazon sign in page

```
public class TC1 extends TestCase {
    @Test
    public void runTC1 () 
    {
        GoToSignInPage gts = new GoToSignInPage(driver);
        gts.clickElement();
    }
}
```

Logic to go to the sign in page is written in GoToSignPage is written

```
public class GoToSignInPage {

    WebDriver driver;

    public GoToSignInPage(WebDriver driver)
    {
        this.driver=driver;
    }

    InitialPage ip = new InitialPage(driver);
    InitializeDriver id = new InitializeDriver();

    public void clickElement()
    {
        Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        //driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        //ip.yourOrders(driver).click();
        jse.executeScript("argument[0].style.border='3px dotted blue'", ip.yourOrders(driver));
action.moveToElement(ip.yourOrders(driver)).moveToElement(ip.signInBt(driver)).click().build().perform();
}
```

InitialPage class has all the required page objects

```
public class InitialPage {

    WebDriver driver;

    public InitialPage(WebDriver driver)
    {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    WebElement element ;

    public WebElement yourOrders(WebDriver driver)
    {
        element = driver.findElement(By.id("nav-link-yourAccount"));
        return(element);

    }
    public WebElement signInBt(WebDriver driver)
    {
        element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='nav-flyout-ya-signin']/a/span"));
        return(element);

    }

}
```

Error is as below

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: argument is not defined
>         (Session info: chrome=56.0.2924.87)
>         (Driver info: chromedriver=2.24.417431 (9aea000394714d2fbb20850021f6204f2256b9cf),platform=Windows NT 6.3.9600 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>       Command duration or timeout: 22 milliseconds
>       Build info: version: '3.0.0-beta1', revision: '8e4315c', time: '2016-07-28 18:04:05 -0700'
>       System info: host: 'VAIO', ip: '192.168.0.6', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_45'
>       Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
>       Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.24.417431 (9aea000394714d2fbb20850021f6204f2256b9cf), userDataDir=C:\Users\Akash\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir6352_11834}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=56.0.2924.87, platform=WIN8_1, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
>       Session ID: f74e69d9f66bab833287a8fd6f9d3021
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

Answer (score 3):

One simple solution is to change jse.executeScript("**argument[0]**.style.border='3px dotted blue'", to jse.executeScript("**arguments[0]**.style.border='3px dotted blue'",

Answer (score 2):

Your error comes from executing this JavaScript code `jse.executeScript("argument[0].style.border='3px dotted blue'"`, try loading the website in your browser (i.e. Chrome), open developer tools (F12), navigate to console, input the same command, and you will get the same error:

[image]

According to [Selenium documentation](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html),

> The arguments will be made available to the JavaScript via the "arguments" variable.

In your code, you use `argument[0]` instead of `arguments[0]`

Comment: But I am passing the argument, the complete command is as below

Comment: based on your comment, it looks like you want to execute the following JavaScript, `document.getElementById('nav-link-yourAccount').style.border='3px dotted blue'`. BTW, this will result in another exception if there is no element with given ID, so, I would add a check condition for that

Comment: another option to try, is to change to `arguments[0]` Note: _s_ at the end of the variable, it is missing in your code

Comment: @AkashChavan : go as per oldbam's latest comment; this is the probable cause to your problem.